# backgroundrb thread_pool.defer method logger output goes to where?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, threadpool, backgroundrb

It seems like due to the threading issue logger.warn (thats what I tested) doesn't generate any output? my code is similar to this:

```
def deliver(args)
  logger.info "delivery start"
  thread_pool.defer(:deliver_deferred, args)
  logger.info "delivery end"
end

def deliver_deferred(args)
  logger.warn "whatsoever"
end
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the specifics, but assuming BackgrounDRb runs as a forked process, any open files would be closed for the forked child process.  This would likely manifest itself as what you're seeing.

However, I would've assumed that BackgrounDRb would've been smart enough to handle that, since it ought to be a pretty obvious issue.